# Android:Use grid view or some else View to show images

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am making an app in which i have to make structure like google play[image]

I don't know whether its **grid view or something else**.I have dynamic images and i have to show images as shown in above image and i don't know how to show images as shown in above .Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose Google Play is a webview in a tabview. Other options is that they are using relative layout. The gridview is like a table, with rows and columns and all equals.

Comment: I think the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679997/in-the-google-play-app-how-is-the-viewgroup-showing-the-application-top-lists-i