# How to create Android Google Play's Grid View like Widget with different size images loaded dynamically

Tags: android-layout, android, google-play

[image]

[image]

Hi
I have enclosed two app images which has grid view like widgets with different image heights and widths, loaded dynamically ,i need to create the same type of UI ,i could be glad if someone guide me to start with.

Comment: Not sure with gridView but using TableLayout you can achieve as above requirement.

Comment: Check out my suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641920/need-a-viewgroupcustomised-for-different-rowheights-with-two-columns-in-androi/14662800#14662800

Answer (score 8):

A similar question was asked previously and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703676/1320263) is the answer.

The developer used [**Bucket List Adapter**](https://github.com/rzsombor/bucket-list-adapter) to create the google play like list view.

Comment: what's new in that code snippet? I have download that but nothing like google play has implemented.

Comment: you need to make a few changes like, instead of TextView, use ImageView. Instead of list contents as integer, just pass the `id` of the drawable you want to display.. You need to do it on trial and error basis

Comment: I tried to implement Bucket List Adapter as iDroid said there i couldn't find anything that would pragmatically calculate the image size and display them.

Comment: @Pallavi I tried with changes as you suggested but still not working. Do you have any other suggestion or demo?

Comment: @Pallavi I have searched a lo but finally i got. Thanks.