# Need a ViewGroup(Customised) for Different Rowheights with two columns in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-gridview

I have infinite number of items. Want to display them in two columns as a GridView with lazy loading. I tried it with GridView, which is displaying all items in a row with the same height. But want it to be adjusted according to the item height as in the attached image. If anyone have any idea or any of u have implemented this with some customized View. Please share it across.
Thanx in advance.[image: ViewGroup with different sized cells]

Comment: Where does #3 go in this picture?

Comment: Nice observation Brian Attwell. But, Don't worry bout those numbers(#s). The concern is about Layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

Look at the `RecyclerView`. The `RecyclerView` replaces `ListView` and is designed to be flexible enough to support your use case.

`RecyclerView` is a part of the support library, added in android L. So it should work on any version of Android. *But beware, at the time of this writing, android L is in preview.*

**Original answer**

There is an experimental class in the Android source code called `StaggeredGridView` that does what you want. It is contained in `frameworks/ex/widgets/` folder.

It isn't finished yet. However, some people have built working prototypes based off it. Ex: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

Comment: Thanx bro. I tried StaggeredGridView. Its giving compile time errors. because my app's min sdk version is 10(Gingerbread). So its not finding some classes, That are there in StaggeredGridView(such as private final **ScrollerCompat** mScroller;). I tried including support libraries and all. But still of no use. Please lemme know, are there any hacks for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I havent heard of any jacks for GB.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for StaggeredGridView suggestion I tried this but it creates problem at time of Orientation change. Do you have any suggestion about this? Thanks.