# How to create Gridview with dynamic height of Image like google play's grideview?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create `GridView` same like google's play(show below image). I search on this and also refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191426/how-to-create-android-google-plays-grid-view-like-widget-with-different-size-im) but still not find any solution.

I have tried `StaggeredGridView` but in this it will create problem while orientation changes. I had also tried with Override `onConfigurationChanged` and in that `gridView.invalidate();` and `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();`But still getting problem.

The Problem is, if I load application in landscape mode and load images and at the time of loading images if I change the orientation then there will be a Gap shown in `GridView`.

Any one has any idea related to this then please share with me.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) which allows user to create a `GridView` with uneven rows similar to how looks like Pinterest,GooglePlay's gridview .

It also Includes own `OnItemClickListener` and `OnItemLongClickListener`, selector, and fixed position restore.

If you already used the StaggeredGridView, then there is also one more [library](https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView) which works the same just you want and also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736658/android-heterogeneous-gridview-like-pinterest) solution .

I hope this serve your purpose.

Hope this helps ... :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already tried this and as I mentioned in my question it will create problem while orientation change.

Comment: Hey I also tried this but I want only grideview in which I can pass NumColums dynamically because it changes while orientation changes.